# java writing to a text file

Tags: java

I would like the following to be printed

test1

test2

test3

test4

But I can't seem to get the text to the next line.

Please help

```
import java.io.*;

public class MainFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                out.write("test " + "\n");
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept the correct answer, people want to get points.

Answer (score 35):

Try `out.newLine();`

So, it would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    out.write("test " + "\n");
    out.newLine();
}
```

[Source (Java API)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29)

Answer (score 8):

You need have two `\n\n` to have a blank line.
Try

```
out.write("test " + "\n\n");
```

In your case(with one `\n`), it will break the current line and move to a new line(which is the next line) but the blank line will not come.

The newline character can be depended on the [platform](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/io/10file/sys-indep-newline.html), so it is better to get the new line character from the java system properties using

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate text, it's probably easier to create a PrintWriter on top of that BufferedWriter, and use the methods in PrintWriter (like println) to do the writing.

Answer (score 1):

The given answer - `System.getProperty("line.separator")`is good enough, but also try `out.write("test " + "\r\n");` it might work, as line break in some OS is `\r\n` and not `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what text editor you are opening the file with and what operating system you are using you might have to use "\r\n" instead of just "\n".

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have an empty catch block, it could be that you're getting an exception and hiding it. Remove the `catch` block and add `throw IOException` to your method definition so if you're getting an exception you can see it.