# Directing output of file to txt file using cmd prompt script and java program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Hey I know there are other questions like this but I am puzzled as to how I can do this the way I want. I want to run my program that basically does something with the given input value then outputs the time it took to do this in ms to a Text File. I want to do this for value starting at 10,000 and incrementing by 10,000 until 200,000 and output the value to a TXT File. Like this

```
for (int i = 10000; i < 200000; i+=10000){
     print i
     java Program i > results.txt
}
```

So out put printed to the text file would be something like:

```
10000    30ms
20000    56ms
30000    75ms
etc      etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: similiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692569/how-can-i-count-the-time-it-takes-a-function-to-complete-in-java

Comment: To a txt file though @cakil

Comment: maybe you can learn from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865453/java-writing-to-a-text-file

Comment: @cakil that's not quite what im after sorry. I want to execute a batch file with a loop like the above, that runs the java program, but im unsure how to implement. Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you mean this:

```
@echo off
(for /l %%i in (10000,10000,200000) do "my Java program" %%i)>"results.txt"
```