# Using XSL transformation for XML to CSV conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I have been working on the xml to csv transform and using [Convert an XML file to CSV file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java) method. However my .xsl file cannot product expected .csv result.

How can I proceed? How should I change my .xsl file?

**here is the my .xml file**:

```
<RowOfValues>
<RowValue>
<Value>XYZ</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>xyz1</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>xyz2</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>xyz3</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>xyz4</Value>
</RowValue>
</RowOfValues>
<RowOfValues>
<RowValue>
<Value>ABC</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>abc1</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>abc2</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>abc3</Value>
</RowValue>
<RowValue>
<Value>abc4</Value>
</RowValue>
</RowOfValues>
```

**here is my .xsl file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        RowValue,Value
            <xsl:for-each select="//RowOfValues">
                <xsl:for-each select="//RowValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Value,',','&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result(csv):**

RowValue,Value

```
XYZ,
xyz1,
xyz2,
xyz3,
xyz4,
ABC,
abc1,
abc2,
abc3,
abc4,
```

**Expected result(csv):**

```
RowValue,Value
XYZ ABC
xyz1,abc1
xyz2,abc2
xyz3,abc3
xyz4,abc4
```

Comment: This is not a valid XML document, as it has no root element.

Comment: @samjudson you are right, but i dont appear all of xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are only 2 columns (i.e. `RowOfValues`), and assuming both columns are of the same length:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('RowValue,Value', '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//RowOfValues[1]/RowValue">
         <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(
                       concat(., ',', //RowOfValues[2]/RowValue[position()=$pos])),
                    '&#xA;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit**

Here's one way to approach the N column case using a call template, although rather imperative :(

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
         xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('RowValue,Value', '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//RowOfValues[1]/RowValue">
         <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="ScrapeColumns">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="ScrapeColumns">
      <xsl:param name="pos"></xsl:param>
      <xsl:for-each select="//RowOfValues[position() > 1]//RowValue[position()=$pos]">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ', normalize-space(.))"/>
      </xsl:for-each>   
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are undoubtedly more elegant solutions.

Comment: many thanks, finally if there are more than 2 columns, how can it implement

Comment: I've updated with an N column version. You would probably want to adjust the column headers as well `RowValue,Value`

Comment: this solution is working properly with last addition.

Answer (score 0):

> if there are more than 2 columns, how can it implement

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="value-by-column" match="Value" use="count(../preceding-sibling::RowValue)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/RowOfValues[1]/RowValue">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('value-by-column', count(preceding-sibling::RowValue))">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will accommodate any number of columns you might have. Note that it is assumed that the number of values in each "column" (i.e. `RowOfValues`) is equal.

When applied to the following test document:

```
<root>
   <RowOfValues>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>Col A</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>a 1</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>a 2</Value>
      </RowValue>
   </RowOfValues>
   <RowOfValues>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>Col B</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>b 1</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>b 2</Value>
      </RowValue>
   </RowOfValues>
   <RowOfValues>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>Col C</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>c 1</Value>
      </RowValue>
      <RowValue>
         <Value>c 2</Value>
      </RowValue>
   </RowOfValues>
</root>
```

the result is:

```
Col A,Col B,Col C
a 1,b 1,c 1
a 2,b 2,c 2
```

Comment: i got a blank csv output according to this solution because of some reason which is not appear in the eclipse.

Comment: @user3560030 You get a blank output using which input? There is a reason why I used my own test input: your input is invalid.