# XML to csv for next level of tag in java

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I have gone thru this solution,but it covers in a single level of nesting, my requirement is thru multilevel of nesting and putting the values in the same row

[Convert an XML file to CSV file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java)

I have this format of input of xml below .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
  <GrpHdr>
    <MsgId>ABC/123</MsgId>
    <NbOfTxs>1000</NbOfTxs>
    <InitgPty>
      <Nm>ABC</Nm>
    </InitgPty>
    <PmtInf>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>00000007010</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
    </PmtInf>
  </GrpHdr>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

My style.xsl below I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL  /Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
MsgId,NbOfTxs,Nm,ID
<xsl:for-each select="//CstmrCdtTrfInitn">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(MsgId,NbOfTxs,',',Nm,',',ID,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the nm and ID in another row,

My code below

```
class Xml2Csv {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File stylesheet = new File("src/main/resources/style.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("src/main/resources/data.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer(stylesource);
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("/tmp/x.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    }
}
```

I would need output like below in CSV

```
MsgId,NbOfTxs,Nm(Inside the InitgPty tag ),ID((Inside the other tag )) as the header 

ABC/123,1000,ABC,00000007010 as values
```

## in a single row

Comment: Oops, indenting the XML shows that you are missing the `</PmtInf>` tag. Dang! XML parse error.

Comment: So you are asking how to write an `XSLT` stylesheet to do this? Starting with the stylesheet that's hidden somewhere on a link you provided. Please update question to include all relevant information, and to show what you have tried so far. --- If you don't know how to write an `XSLT` stylesheet, I'd suggest you start reading about it.

Comment: Can u pls try and see what u get. Please spell you words in full. --- Do you understand the XSLT? What is does? How it works? Have you read anything about XSLT? If not, maybe try a non-XSLT solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access nested nodes in your XML, you need to specify the full path to each node in your expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(GrpHdr/MsgId,GrpHdr/NbOfTxs,',',GrpHdr/InitgPty/Nm,',',GrpHdr/PmtInf/DbtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id,'&#xA;')"/>
```

You could potentially simplify the statement by selecting `GrpHdr` elements instead of just `CstmrCdtTrfInitn`.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MsgId,NbOfTxs,Nm,ID</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(MsgId,NbOfTxs,',',InitgPty/Nm,',',PmtInf/DbtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect ,I just replaced with GrpHdr and it displayed all the records, Tks a bunch. My time is considerably saved .