# Convert xml to csv with xsl java

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

i am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java)
i want to convert an xml to csv
i have an xml and written and xsl for it
openning xml with href to the xsl  work on internet explorer
but runing the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java) return an error
Can not resolve namespace prefix: xmlns

what should fix it ?

i have a working xml & xsl

**xml**

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="student2.xsl"?>
    <rankings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ign="http://api.DomainName.com/2.0" count="438" total="438" offset="0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.DomainName.com/2.0 http://api.DomainName.com/2.0/api.xsd"  >
      <ranking keyword="80s fancy dress">
    <ranks>
      <rank week="201526" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
      <rank week="201527" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
      <rank week="201528" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
      <rank week="201529" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
      <rank week="201530" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
      <rank week="201531" country="uk" searchengine="google_uk_en">NR</rank>
    </ranks>
  </ranking> 
</rankings>
```

---

**xsl**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://api.DomainName.com/2.0" exclude-result-prefixes=xmlns>
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
 <table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
 </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="rankings/ranking/ranks/rank">
 <tr>
 <keyword><xsl:value-of select="../../@keyword"/></keyword>
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
 <week><xsl:value-of select="@week"/></week>
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
 <country><xsl:value-of select="@country"/></country>
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
 <searchengine><xsl:value-of select="@searchengine"/></searchengine>
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
 <rank><xsl:value-of select="../rank"/></rank>
 <xsl:value-of select="." />
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

java code

after running the java code from the above link
i get an error

```
(Location of error unknown)org.xml.sax.SAXException: Can not resolve namespace prefix: xmlns
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1060)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1268)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1251)
```

Comment: If you want .csv as your output, why are you constructing an HTML document with a <table>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should fix it ?

To eliminate the error, you need to remove this:

```
exclude-result-prefixes=xmlns
```

from your `xsl:stylesheet` tag. You also need to remove the default namespace declaration:

```
xmlns="http://api.DomainName.com/2.0"
```

otherwise all your output will be placed in that namespace, which you most certainly don't want to happen if - as it seems - you want it to be HTML.

There are other changes you need to make - for example, if you want to output an HTML table, set the output method to "html" instead of "text", and make sure your table structure is valid.

---

**Note**:

Your XML declares a namespace: `xmlns:ign="http://api.DomainName.com/2.0"` but this namespace declaration isn't used anywhere. Therefore your stylesheet can ignore it. Provided you are showing us a representative sample of the real XML.