# Xml parsing on Apache Kafka

Tags: java, xml, apache-kafka

I am using Apache Kafka to read in an multiple xml files. I want to convert the xml files into a flat file (csv file or text file). I have an example output below:

I think converting xml into dom is a solution or using Jackson-xml data converter?

Can anyone comment on the best solution to achieve this? Thanks!

Input 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <id>123</id>
   <firstName>Jane</firstName>
   <phoneNumbers type="work">555-1111</phoneNumbers>
</customer>
```

Input 2:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customer>
       <id>1234</id>
       <firstName>Bob</firstName>
       <phoneNumbers type="work">555-1111</phoneNumbers>
    </customer>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><customer><id>123</id><firstName>Jane</firstName><phoneNumbers type="work">555-1234</phoneNumbers></customer>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><customer><id>1234</id><firstName>Bob</firstName><phoneNumbers type="work">555-1111</phoneNumbers></customer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. One way to do it is bash... look below

```
#!/bin/bash

>combined.csv
for xml in *.xml
do
  echo "Processing $xml";
  id=$({ xmllint --xpath "string(//customer/id)" $xml; echo ","; } | tr "\n" " ");
  firstname=$({ xmllint --xpath "string(//customer/firstName)" $xml; echo ","; } | tr "\n" " ");
  phonenumber=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//customer/phoneNumbers)" $xml);
  line="${id}${firstname}${phonenumber}\n"
  printf "$line" >> combined.csv
done
```

Comment: Oh interesting solution. How do I iterate through a whole series of xml without hardcoding every field? The real file is really long and has lots of fields.

Comment: I would try to use xpath to get all the names of a node, and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with `java` I'll assume you're using Kafka Producer java client.

If that's the case then you can do the conversion in your Producer implementation, using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java).