# XML parsing in JAVA using DOM, xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am newbie in java.I am trying to parse XML Document in JAVA using DOM parser. But i am unable to getting values from XML Document. How to convert XML file tag fields XSL file tags?

**Here is my XML Document:**

```
    <response>
<row> 
 <row _id = "1570186"
      _uuid = "D284E0E9-9807-491F-9A1D-21CB47ABED10"
      _position = "1570186"
      _address = "http://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/_4mse-ku6q/1570186"> 
 </row>
 </row>
</response>
```

this above file convert to xsl file.
i refer url: [Convert an XML file to CSV file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java)

Comment: What do you want to say to the world with "how to convert xml file tag fields xsl file tags". I do not understand what is the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) you can find an example of XML parsing using `org.w3c.dom` library.