# Get value from parent and child tag from a xml file using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert an XML file to CSV and I am taking help from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413978/convert-an-xml-file-to-csv-file-using-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but struck in a place where I have to retrieve the value from a parent tag and some specific child tag from an XML file. My input XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Payslip>
    <StaffNumber>123456</StaffNumber>
    <StaffName>ALIBABA</StaffName>
    <Sex/>      
    <PayDetails>
        <PayType>NORMAL</PayType>
        <AmountNet>2100</AmountNet> 
        <ComponentDetails>
            <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
            <ComponentSource/>
            <Code>SAL</Code>
        </ComponentDetails>                     
        <ComponentDetails>
            <ComponentType>DED</ComponentType>
            <ComponentSource/>
            <Code>DEN</Code>
        </ComponentDetails>     
    </PayDetails>
    <LeaveTaken>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate/>
        <Balance>0</Balance>
    </LeaveTaken>
</Payslip>
```

My xsl file looks like this, pls note I have put few hardcoded value for some other requirement.

I'm fairly new to XSLT so please excuse the potential novice question. Any guidance would be appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

### style.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> Worker,Pay_Group,Pay_Period_End_Date,Payment_Date,Net_Amount,Gross_Amount,Currency,Ck_Number,Display_Date
    <xsl:for-each select="//Payslip">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(StaffNumber,',','PAY_GROUP',',','2017-09-24-00:00',',','2017-09-27-00:00',',',AmountNet,',','AmountGross',',','AUD',',','393',',','SLP000393_',StaffNumber,'.pdf',',','&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above code if I use

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Payslip">
```

then I am getting only StaffNumber and staffName fields but if I use

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Payslip//PayDetails">
```

to get value from the AmountNet tag then it fails to fetch value from the StaffNumber tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only the values of the `StaffNumber` and `StaffName` because they are direct descendants of the `Payslip` node. In order to get the values of the other nodes, you must specify the correct XPath expressions for each of them.

For example in order to get the value of the `AmountNet` you should refer to its path as:

```
PayDetails/AmountNet
```

instead of just

```
AmountNet
```

since the current node inside the for-each loop is the `Payslip` node.

**Update**

Leave the `<xsl:for-each select="//Payslip">` to refer the `Payslip` node. Just change the line below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(StaffNumber,',','PAY_GROUP',',','2017-09-24-00:00',',','2017-09-27-00:00',',',AmountNet,',','AmountGross',',','AUD',',','393',',','SLP000393_',StaffNumber,'.pdf',',','&#xA;')"/>
```

to the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(StaffNumber,',','PAY_GROUP',',','2017-09-24-00:00',',','2017-09-27-00:00',',',PayDetails/AmountNet,',','AmountGross',',','AUD',',','393',',','SLP000393_',StaffNumber,'.pdf',',','&#xA;')"/>
```

Comment: One more problem I am facing. If two tags are at the same level and I want to fetch the value from the first tag and from the second tag which contains multiple child and sub child, for which I have to use iterator then how do I select the values, and finally how do print result from both the tags.